# reader.getNumberOfPages() is always printing zero

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm trying to read a PDF through iText API, PDF Reader. When I try to print the number of pages in my console, I always get zero even though my PDF has 10 pages and all 10 pages have some content in it (they are not blank). Below is the code snippet I used and the console output.

Please help me to resolve this,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("D:\\JEE(Main)_AcknowledgementPage (1).pdf");
        int number_of_pages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
        System.out.println("Number of pages is ...."+number_of_pages);
        for (int i = 0; i < number_of_pages;) {
            System.out.println("Inside for loop");
        }
    } catch (Exception i) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

My Console output:

```
    Number of pages is ....0
```

Comment: Maybe your PDF file is actually an XFA file. Do you have the same problem with a normal PDF file? Also: you're using iText 1.2.3??? That's crazy! Please upgrade!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using correct API. It is returning correct number of pages for me.
However your for loop is wrong

```
for (int i = 0; i < number_of_pages;) {
            System.out.println("Inside for loop");
        }
```

You are not increasing value of i anywhere after i < number_of_pages.
It should be like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < number_of_pages; i++) {
        System.out.println("Inside for loop");
    }
```

Here you go, the complete code is here what I am using.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(
            "C:/anil/code/StackOverFlow/res/mySample.pdf");
int number_of_pages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
System.out.println("Number of pages is ...."+number_of_pages);
for (int i = 0; i < number_of_pages; i++) {
        System.out.println("Inside for loop");
}
```

Comment: I use the API iText 1.2.3 and that for loop was a typing mistake.Can you please share the code that you are using?

Comment: I used iText-2.1.4 and tested the above code with a couple of files.  There might be something wrong with your pdf file (password protected or unable to read), that's what I am guessing

Comment: I changed the jar to 2.1.4 and it worked fine:) thank you so much Anil :)

Comment: Thank you Anju, if my answer helped, please mark it as answered

Comment: I upvoted the answer, but please upgrade to a more recent version. iText 2.1.4 dates from November 2008. It is no longer supported. It is no longer distributed (you can't download it from an **official** iText server) and there are known legal and technical problems with it: [Can iText 2.1.7 or earlier be used commercially?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/can-itext-217-or-earlier-be-used-commercially) If you use iText 2.1.4 for a customer, you are now officially informed of these problems. If a customer ever complains, you can't say you didn't know about this.

Comment: We use it at our company and we have licenses for it. :)  We are aware of licensing changes that iText has gone through.